# When using ttk buttons with emojis as the text, why do some appear different?

Tags: python, tkinter, emoji, ttk

Tkinter ver 8.6, py 3.10.4 x64

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
root = tk.Tk()
root.grid()
button1 = ttk.Button(text="️").grid(column=0, row=0)
button2 = ttk.Button(text="✊").grid(column=0, row=1)
button3 = ttk.Button(text="").grid(column=0, row=2)
button4 = ttk.Button(text="").grid(column=0, row=3)


root.mainloop()
```

For some reason, this displays the emojis at different sizes and the first is not even centered, see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehCbg.png) (stackoverflow won't let me attach images)

Even when using unicode escape sequences instead of the actual emoji in the string, they all appear to be [vastly different sizes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ur1yz.png) (Although this fixes the centering issue).

Firstly, why does this occur? Why do different emoji's appear to have different spacing, at least in a tkinter window? Changing font does not appear to fix this issue.

Secondly, why does using the unicode escape sequence cause the layout to have less issues? Shouldn't it be displayed similarly, as the text in the button should be the same? I  understand it may affect internal operations but shouldn't it be visually identical in output?

Comment: Different fonts may have different results.  It is ok when I use "Noto Emoji" font, see [result image](https://i.imgur.com/krghGAw.png).

Comment: Interesting, thank you @acw1668. I take it this must be an issue with certain fonts rather than an issue with tkinter itself then? Although it only appearing on tkinter (as far as I am aware) may suggest otherwise. Either way, thank you for the comment, it's definitely an easy workaround for this issue.